# How to mark junkmail as spam in Corporate Gmail

Tags: gmail-filters, spam-prevention

Our office administrator booked me for some travel through Travelocity and provided my email address. Now my inbox is filling up with spam from Travelocity (multiple pieces of junk a day on a low volume account). I've asked to be removed multiple times, but Travelocity simply ignores the request.

The two addresses that appear to be utilized by Travelocity when spamming are:

- no-reply@mg.travelocity.com
- travelocity@mg.travelocity.com

Corporate Gmail has a *Filter* in *Settings*, but they don't allow me to mark spam from the addresses as spam.

How can I add a filter to mark Travelocity as spam when using Corporate Gmail?

I'm also open to suggestions to get their emails into a Blackhole list to disrupt their spamming operation across the globe.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you asked Travelocity to remove your emails, but personally I would both email them to a relevant contact email like [contact@travelocity.com](http://www.travelocity.com/p/support.htm#Contact) or try to login to the site and change your notifications settings with the credentials your office administrator used.

But, if it all fails go to the email and:

1. Click on the down-pointing arrow and choose "Filter messages like this".

[image]

2. Click on "Create filter with this search" (bottom right).
3. Check "Delete it".
4. Check "Also apply filter to X matching conversations" (bottom).
5. Click on Create Filter.

You are done.

Comment: Thanks Peter. I don't want to delete it. I want to mark it as spam so it will be properly classified. Once classified, future junk mailings can be filtered automatically. Also, I don't have an account on their site. Finally, I've been emailing (1) the addresses they used in the junk mail, (2) the Technical and Administrative contacts from the WHOIS database, and (3) email addresses from RFC 2142, MAILBOX NAMES FOR COMMON SERVICES.

Comment: Hey JWW, I came across this Lifehacker post. Maybe it will help overcome admin restrictions http://lifehacker.com/5875848/how-can-i-find-out-why-my-email-account-just-spammed-my-friends-and-family